# Most frequent occurrence (mode) of numpy array values based on IDs in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-D array containing values and I would like to calculate the most frequent entry (i.e., the mode) from this data according to IDs in a second array.

```
data = np.array([[[ 0, 10, 50, 80, 80],
                  [10, 10, 50, 80, 90],
                  [10, 10, 50, 80, 90],
                  [50, 50, 80, 80, 80]])


ID = np.array([[[ 1,  1, 2, 3, 3],
                  [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                  [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                  [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]])


#Expected Result is:

[10 50 80]
```

The most frequent value in data array for ID=1 is 10, ID=2 is 50 and ID=3 is 80. I've been playing around with `np.unique` and combinations of `np.bincount` and `np.argmax` but I can't figure out how to get the result. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible vectorized way to do it, if you have integer data and the number of different values and groups is not too huge.

```py
import numpy as np

# Input data
data = np.array([[[ 0, 10, 50, 80, 80],
                  [10, 10, 50, 80, 90],
                  [10, 10, 50, 80, 90],
                  [50, 50, 80, 80, 80]]])
ID = np.array([[[1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]]])
# Find unique data values and group ids with reverse indexing
data_uniq, data_idx = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
id_uniq, id_idx = np.unique(ID, return_inverse=True)
# Number of unique data values
n = len(data_uniq)
# Number of ids
m = len(id_uniq)
# Change indices so values of each group are within separate intervals
grouped = data_idx + (n * np.arange(m))[id_idx]
# Count repetitions and reshape
# counts[i, j] has the number of apparitions of the j-th value in the i-th group
counts = np.bincount(grouped, minlength=n * m).reshape(m, n)
# Get the modes from the counts
modes = data_uniq[counts.argmax(1)]
# Print result
for group, mode in zip(id_uniq, modes):
    print(f'Mode of {group}: {mode}')
```

Output:

```
Mode of 1: 10
Mode of 2: 50
Mode of 3: 80
```

---

A quick benchmark for a particular problem size:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

def find_group_modes_loop(data, ID):
    # Assume ids are given sequentially starting from 1
    m = ID.max()
    modes = np.empty(m, dtype=data.dtype)
    for id in range(m):
        modes[id] = scipy.stats.mode(data[ID == id + 1])[0][0]
    return modes

def find_group_modes_vec(data, ID):
    # Assume ids are given sequentially starting from 1
    data_uniq, data_idx = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
    id_uniq = np.arange(ID.max(), dtype=data.dtype)
    n = len(data_uniq)
    m = len(id_uniq)
    grouped = data_idx + (n * np.arange(m))[ID.ravel() - 1]
    counts = np.bincount(grouped, minlength=n * m).reshape(m, n)
    return data_uniq[counts.argmax(1)]

# Make data
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(0, 1_000, size=10_000_000)
ID = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10_000_000)
print(np.all(find_group_modes_loop(data, ID) == find_group_modes_vec(data, ID)))
# True
%timeit find_group_modes_loop(data, ID)
# 212 ms ± 647 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit find_group_modes_vec(data, ID)
# 122 ms ± 3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So at least for some cases the vectorized solution can be significantly faster than looping.

Comment: I like this vectorized approach best as it runs quicker and logically fits with my code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use scipy `mode`

```
from scipy.stats import mode

uniq_ids = np.unique(ID)
modes = []

for id in uniq_ids:
    modes.append(mode(data[ID == id])[0][0])
```

modes

`[10 50 80]`

Answer (score 2):

I have applied this approach in numpy, I hope this will solve your issue.

`n,f=np.unique(data[np.where(ID == 1)],return_counts=True)`

Output:
`(array([ 0, 10, 50]), array([1, 5, 1]))`

The output is tuple of the values and their respective frequencies

You could get value with maximum frequencies like this

`n[np.argmax(f)]`

The proper solution will be:

`res = []
for id in np.unique(ID):
  n,f = np.unique(data[np.where(ID == id)],return_counts=True)
  res.append(n[np.argmax(f)])`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure numpy solution, you can reinvent the wheel in [@Kenan's loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59899827/2988730):

```
def mode(x):
    n, c = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    return n[np.argmax(c)]

modes = [mode(data[ID == id]) for id in np.unique(IDs)]
```